# Kafka Connect - Not working for UPDATE operation

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am new to Kafka-Connect source and sink. I created application to transfer Table Data from one Schema (Schema1) to another Schema (Schema2), here I used Oracle as a Database. I **successfully transferred data/row for INSERT operation** from Table "Schema1.Header" to Table "Schema2.Header", but **not working for UPDATE operation** with below mentioned config.

SOURCE Config:

```
          {
           "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
            "connection.url": "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1524:XE",
            "connection.user": "USER",
            "connection.password": "user1234",
            "dialect.name": "OracleDatabaseDialect",
            "topic.prefix": "Schema1.Header",
            "incrementing.column.name": "SC_NO",
            "mode": "incrementing",
            "query": "SELECT * FROM (SELECT HEADER_V1.* FROM Schema1.Header HEADER_V1 INNER JOIN Schema1.LINE_V1 LINE_V1 ON HEADER_V1.SC_NO = LINE_V1.SC_NO AND LINE_V1.CLNAME_CODE ='XXXXXX' AND HEADER_V1.ITEM_TYPE = 'XXX')",
            "transforms": "ReplaceField",
            "transforms.ReplaceField.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ReplaceField$Value",
            "transforms.ReplaceField.blacklist": "col_3,col_10"
            }
```

SINK Config:

```
  {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
    "connection.url": "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1524:XE",
    "connection.user": "USER2",
    "connection.password": "user21234",
    "dialect.name": "OracleDatabaseDialect",
    "topics": "Schema1.Header",
    "table.name.format": "Schema2.Header",
    "tasks.max": "1"
}
```

Kindly help me to fix this issue.

Note : I need to do all CRUD operations in Schema Schema1.Tables only, Using Kafka connect am transferring those data to another Schema Schema2.Tables. Newly inserted data/row got transferred but updated data/row not transferred via Kafka-Connect. What I have to do achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [blog](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-jdbc-source-connector/?_ga=2.242664011.856618672.1600704303-1221623284.1596107588) you need to set the `mode` to `timestamp` (or better `timestamp+incrementing` if you want to both *new* and *updated* rows) in your source config.

In addition, you then need to specify the `timestamp.column.name` which should point to a timestamp column that is updated every time the row is updated.